# WCF Rest Service in JSON and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

I'm getting some problems exposing a WCF REST Service in JSON and trying to consume it from jQuery.

- The first and desired approach I took was very similar to [this](http://www.practicaldeveloper.net/2012/05/restful-wcf-services-with-jquery-mobile.html). However I faced the problem that returning JSON with the IsReference=true annotation wasn't OK, althought if I returned XML it was OK.
- The second approach was returning XML and playing in jQuery with it. But as jQuery likes JSON I don't like this option.
- Another one may have been trying with JSON.Net following [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Supporting-different-data-b0351c9a) solution but in the description the author says it isn't recommended for production.
- What I have now is the first approach with the annotation IsReference=false, which is kinda dangeourous I think, and to solve the circular references I have manually delete those cycles like for example:

---

```
var queryResult =
    from a in DbContext.Programs.Include(x => x.Radios)
    where ProgramsIds.Contains(a.Id)
    select a;

foreach (Program p in queryResult)
{
    p.Radio = null;
    p.Messages = new List<Message>();
}
```

---

I don't like this solution but I don't know which one is the less bad.

I suppose many people may have had this problem, which solution did you take?

Thanks!!

Edit 1:

- Another solution is to make the call to a Controller/Action which is responsible for making the call to the service. I also don't like this approach because it's innecesary as the browser can go and hit the service by itself.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.Net handles object/reference hierarchy correctly. So just get json string from your queryResult with JSON.Net serializer (or with ServiceStack.Text serializer ) and return Stream from service method:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetJson", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)] //ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
Stream GetJSON(); 

....
return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
```